# ImageResizer error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, imageresizer

I'm using the Image Resizer imageresizing.net. But, when I'm trying to upload or resize an image, an error occurs:

> The source stream is at the end (have you already read it?). You must call stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); before re-using a stream, or use ImageJob with ResetSourceStream=true the first time the stream is read.

```
using (Stream newFile =  System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(_pathResolver.ResolvePath(_appSettings.CompanyLogosDirectory), newFileName)) )
{
     //newFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

     ImageResizer.ImageJob i = new ImageJob();
     //i.ResetSourceStream = true;
     i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(logo.InputStream, newFile, new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings("width=120;height=45;format=jpg;mode=max"));

     i.CreateParentDirectory = false; //Auto-create the uploads directory.
     i.Build();
}
```

Comment: Well from the code you posted it's hard to say but...are you sure you have any valid image in the source stream? Sometimes error messages are meaningful...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have used `logo.InputStream` before provided code (maybe for other job). You can read image again or as exception suggested put below code before `using` statement:

```
logo.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```